# In the stripe customer portal, is there a way to show more information for the user's subscription?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a react app that uses Stripe to process payments.

The user can create multiple messaging groups and invite other users to their groups.

The user can then "upgrade" their group by subscribing to a premium product.

I'm using the Stripe customer portal to let the users manage their subscriptions. Currently, it only shows a list of the user's subscriptions like so:

Current Plans:

- Premium, 9.99$ per month
- Premium, 9.99$ per month
- Premium, 9.99$ per month
- ...

I would like to show the name of the group associated with each subscription:

Current Plans:

- Premium for John's Group, 9.99$ per month
- Premium for Greg's Group, 9.99$ per month
- ...

How could I customize the Customer Portal?

Thank you

Comment: Add some code, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not supported. On subscription-related interfaces (invoices, checkout, customer portal), the displayed text is derived from the `product[name]` for the Product associated with the Price being used. To display separate "names" you'd need to have separate Prices with separate Product references, where each Product has a distinct `name`.